# Securing apache server Virtual hosts

Tags: security, virtualhost, ubuntu-11.04

first off my set up:

Ubuntu Server 11 with full LAMP installed

Sample of my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
NamevirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.web.com
ServerAlias www.web.com
ServerAdmin me.co.uk
DocumentRoot "/var/www/web"
DirectoryIndex index.php
Alias /pdf /var/www/web/pdf/Order_pdf
Alias /glass /var/www/web/pdf/Glass_order_pdf
ErrorLog "/var/www/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "/var/www/logs/access.log" combined
CustomLog "/var/www/logs/deflate.log" deflate
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.intranet.com
ServerAlias www.intranet.com
ServerAdmin me.co.uk
DocumentRoot "/var/www/intranet"
DirectoryIndex Search.php
ErrorLog "/var/www/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "/var/www/logs/access.log" combined
CustomLog "/var/www/logs/deflate.log" deflate
</VirtualHost>
```

I have my router forwarding port 80 to my server and it is correctly showing www.web.com I want to somehow block any external access to the intranet site but not exactly sure how to do this, hope someone can help?

Would this be something I need to use?

```
<Directory "/var/www/web">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
Allow Override None
Order deny,alow
deny from all
allow list 192.168.1.0/24
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this has been answered elsewhere. Anyway if you want to use IP check on you intranet you can do this.

```
<Directory /var/www/intranet/>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
</Directory>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I have tried to figure this out but just needed some friendly advise as wasn't confident

Comment: I have just added this and now the site is unavailable??

Comment: What does you error log say or does the web server barf on startup? Do you sit on the specified subnet? Where did you put the snippet? It should be within the Virtualhost of the intranet site.

Comment: when web server restarts error: NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts?

Comment: My bad, I've changed the syntax in the snippet above.